# minecraft item frame not outputting redstone signal when item turned

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have an item frame on a block of emerald. In the item frame there is an anvil. I'm using vanilla Minecraft 1.9. When I turn the item in the item frame no signal comes out of the comparator. I have also placed a comparator behind the block. No difference.

[image: Start]

[image: 1 click]

[image: 2 click][image: 4 click]

After a few more clicks...

[image: 7 click]
[image: all done]

As you can see the piston never extended. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to put the comparator behind the block with the itemframe on it:
[image]
[image]

Comment: i have tried that.

Comment: @HarounMohamed-Fakier If you are saying this does not work then check again.

Comment: Sorry, I re-checked. I was using the wrong minecraft version. Thank you very much.